# How do you return a string between two tags, without returning the tags (using only regex)

Tags: c#, regex

```
        string x = "[string] two[string] (1thing)";
        Regex sort1 = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");
        MatchCollection sortOpen = sort1.Matches(x);
        foreach (Match y in sortOpen)
        {
            ..
        }
```

returns with the brackets: how do you return the string without the tags that are used to sort?

Comment: yup, care to explain that tho? haha ?<= and ?= ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])
```

In .NET. `(?<=expression)` matches the `expression` **prefix** but excludes it from the capture, while `(?=expression)` matches the `expression` **suffix** but excludes it from the capture.